# how extract only date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When I retrieve the date value from c# it will be in the following format:

```
/Date(1406844000000)/
```

then in JavaScript i make this code :

```
var date1 = new Date(parseInt(ret.startDate.substr(6)));
```

and when I display this value in label it display as follow:

```
Fri Aug 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time)
```

and I need only

```
Fri Aug 01 2014
```

How extract only date in java script from above value?

Comment: Ok ... Apple or Orange ? Please select one.

Comment: Mango, apparently. Javascript is neither C# nor Java...

Comment: what do you mean? @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: what do you mean? @Jon Skeet

Comment: @AlaaKhalil It means you have to choose proper tags while asking a question. You are asking a JavaScript question and tagging Java and C#. So do you want to solve your problem using those languages ?

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the date to a string.

```
date1.toString().substr(0, 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date1.toDateString()
```

or if you want it localized:

```
date1.toLocaleDateString()
```